# Визуальный конструктор запросов, архитектуры базы и автоматическая миграция для sqlite

Tags: javascript, мобильная-разработка

Есть что для мобильной разработки на javascript? Что бы схему базы на sqlite где-то нарисовать и как ресурс к проекту подключать, что бы можно было автоматически апдейтить. И визуальный конструктор запросов, из которого получившийся текст запроса можно было бы копировать?